# Force applications to open in the foreground when launched from iexplore

Tags: windows-7, command-line, internet-explorer-8

I have a slight problem with my project I've working on...

I have replaced explorer with iexplore in kiosk mode.  iexplore loads a speeddial type of webpage for a set of windows programs. I launch those programs with PHP's system().

The problem is, when the programs launch, they launch BEHIND iexplore instead of in front of it.

How can I force the programs being launched to ALWAYS load in the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

Check for an option in iexplorer's config panel to see if there is an option to keep iexplorer on top always, if there is an option like that, disable that option.

Comment: Sometimes the app will launch in front - there's no lock caused by ie, I think it is something about the window order or whatever had focus last.

I'm going to try http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html which has commands along the like of: win [action] [find] [window to find] [Additional Parameters]

title: Finds the desired window by specifying the exact title of the window in [window to find] parameter.
activate: Bring the specified window to the front.
focus: Set the focus to the specified window.

Which will actually solve a few problems.